# selecting Month from time stamp

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to fetch data according to month.
Date is stored in timestamp.

```
select pdate,COUNT(*) from qchat_sessions WHERE month(pdate)='09'
```

i am using this query but thats not working correctly.

and how to echo the date from time stamp

Thanks

**EDIT1**

Mainly what i want to do is to echo the  dates from that month with no of rows.
in db i have two dates :  `2013-09-27` and `2013-09-28`
but using:

`$sss=mysql_query("SELECT DATE(pdate),COUNT(*) FROM qchat_sessions WHERE MONTH(pdate)='09'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($sss);
$a = array($rows[0],$rows[1]);

foreach ($a as $b)

{

print $b . " ";

It echos only 1 date may be i am missing something.
 } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(pdate) as pdate,COUNT(*) 
FROM qchat_sessions 
WHERE MONTH(pdate)='10';
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT DATE(pdate) as pdate,COUNT(*) 
FROM qchat_sessions 
WHERE MONTH(pdate)='10'
GROUP BY DATE(pdate);
```

**EDIT**

You can use this code printing the data. Edit as your wish

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sss)) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];
}
```

Comment: ok..but not echoing correctly. I want to echo each date of that month with count of the date

Comment: check this fiddle this is what i need http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcc0b/3 but not working in php

Comment: Thanks...works perfeclty. dont know why i didnt got this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   select pdate,COUNT(*) from qchat_sessions WHERE month(FROM_UNIXTIME(pdate))='10'
```

Comment: i used `date('m-d-Y',$row['pdate']);` to echo date it returns `01-01-1970` but actual date is `2013-09-28 07:39:10`

Comment: In such a case, my advice is calculate by php. after query:$count=mysql_num_rows($sss); and remove from query COUNT(*)

Comment: hi, now i have used foreach and its also echoing only date may be i am doing something wrong ..plz check **EDIT1**

Comment: check this fiddle this is what i need sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcc0b/3 but not working in php

Comment: Use `while`. `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sss)){ echo $row['mydate'].'-'.$row['mycount]; }`